# ASP.Net MVC5 как сбросить настройки на дефалтные

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Установил я VS15, создал пустой проект MVC5. И там буквально ничего нет. Создал папку Controllers, в неё закинул HomeController, затем создал структуру папок (всё по соглашению как в MVC4) и туда закинул представление для контроллера, но при запуске проекта всё время выводит Hello World!. Нашёл файл Sturtup.cs и там были прописаны строки

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

    app.Run(async (context) =>
    {
        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
    });
}
```

Вот как мне сбросить настройки до дефалтных? Чтобы запускался метод index контроллера Home?

Comment: вопрос версий ASP.NET и ASP.NET MVC собьет с толку любого :)) MVC 5 живет в ASP.NET 4, а в ASP.NET 5 живет MVC 6 :)).

Comment: небольшое описание, что с этим делать http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/conceptual-overview/understanding-aspnet5-apps.html

Answer (score 2):

Пример вашего кода, это ASP.NET 5 MVC 6. С чего начать можно почитать в русской документации [ASP.NET 5 тут](http://dotnet.today/ru/aspnet5-vnext/tutorials/your-first-aspnet-application.html) и [тут MVC 6](http://dotnet.today/ru/aspnet5-mvc6/getting-started/first-mvc-app/start-mvc.html)